# Python CSV or Pd Dataframe Parsing Question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

I have a csv file or pd dataframe object with labels on both axis (columns and rows). I need to check the values of each cell and if the value is True, I need to print the corresponding axis labels (both axis) for the values. I spent some time and couldn't find a solution out there in Python. Really appreciate any help.

Something like this:

```
['', 'column_name_1', 'column_name_2', 'column_name_3',...] 
['Row_1_name', 'False', 'False', 'True'...] 
['Row_2_name', 'False', 'False', 'True'...]
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail about the dataframe? And do you need to save the  labels in some way or just list them?

Comment: please see my edits, this is the csv format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that prints index and column of all `True` values in a dataframe by applying a print function to all columns:

```
import pandas
import io

data = '''col1,col2
label1,False,True
label2,True,False
label3,False,True'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), engine='python')

def print_labels(x):
    for label, val in x.iteritems():
        if val: #insert your own validation here (or filter the column before the loop)
            print(label, x.name)

df.apply(print_labels, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
label2 col1
label1 col2
label3 col2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this. Have a good one!

Comment: Why did label2 print before label1?

Comment: @ZachYoung because `axis=0` passes columns. Use `axis=1` for a row-wise approach.